# Limit in Search API not working?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, gae-search

I added 11 documents with a numeric field set to 1 to 11. And set sorting on the numeric field.

```
    SortOptions sortOptions = SortOptions.newBuilder()
            .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder()
                    .setExpression(NUMERIC_FIELD)
                    .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.DESCENDING)
                    .setDefaultValue("0"))
            .setLimit(1000)
            .build();
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
            .setLimit(maxResults)                       
            .setSortOptions(sortOptions)
            .setCursor(cursor)
            .build();
    Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(queryString);
```

When maxResults is set to 11 or higher it works fine, but for lower values the results returned are ordered incorrectly. Before I post this as a bug, have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Try setting the default sort value to 0 (numeric) instead of "0" (string) -- does that fix it?

Comment: Edit to the above-- you will need to use `setDefaultValueNumeric(0)` to set the default instead.  In my tests, this works for me.

Comment: Still the same problem. Good to know about setDefaultValueNumeric(), I had missed that but the problem remains. I'm running only on the developer server and I have deleted all content under directory appengine-generated several times which may have messed things up, I don't know. Will test it on the production server later on.